PCA site scores much smaller than 'species' scores?
This question is similar to another one on DCA (Spread of species and site scores in R (vegan) DCA ordination), though I believe I'm using the correct analysis and data pre-processing.
I'm using PCA (unconstrained RDA in vegan) to explore which landscape variables best differentiate spaces (2500 m$^2$ grid cells) in an urban environment. There are currently 16 landscape variables, like wetlands, flood zones, forest, hardscapes, etc. (as proportion (%) coverage of grid cells, expressed as whole numbers from 0 to 100), and proximity (inverted distances) to other features (e.g., roads, waterfront, also expressed as score from 0 to 100 (where 100 = within or immediately adjacent to the feature, 0 representing max distance from the features). Expressing percentages out of 100, and distances as a proximity score out of 100, seemed like a solid 'manual' standardization that didn't require too much distortion of the variables.
I used A-D normality test, and all variables normally distributed. All basically continuous. All positive values (0 or higher).
I have a huge number of grid cells (>16,000), relative to the number of variables (16). Using rda on an unscaled data frame because I've already constrained all data to a 0-100 scale.
PCA <- rda(land_data, scale=FALSE) 
#note, results similar if scale=TRUE

Results looked good, with 1st 2 PCs explaining 79% of variance (inertia). However, when I look at 'site' (grid cells) and 'species' (landscape variables) scores, and plot the PCA, the site scores are all an order of magnitude smaller than the 'species' scores. Results in biplots with sites all clustered in the middle and huge spread for landscape variables ('species'). Again, doesn't change if I scale the PCA. I'd show an example, but I don't know how to load an image. Below are some example scores. The correlations among landscape variables make sense (there are some intentionally redundant variables in there, almost as a methods check). However, I expect I've done something wrong, because PCAs typically have site and species scores with a similar spread, so they plot well together. I suspected it was a function of my very high sample size, so I subset the data to 25 rows. This didn't really change the proportions or scores (sites vs. species) much.
Site scores (weighted sums of species scores)

       PC1      PC2       PC3     PC4      PC5     PC6
1  -4.2021  2.66822  0.483954 -9.1781  6.73713 -6.2371
2  -4.2175  2.50282 -0.007664 -6.9943  1.55588 -2.1946
3  -4.2422  2.27797 -0.737687 -5.3532 -6.40043  3.8969
4  -2.2496 -3.75241  0.537407 -4.8761 -5.68304  4.3726

Species scores

                         PC1        PC2        PC3        PC4
Waterfront_Prox    1.889e+00  6.305e-01  1.017e+00  1.539e+00
Forest_proximity   1.875e-15  1.363e-15  6.360e-16  9.218e-16
Res_Proximity     -9.021e-02 -2.470e-02 -6.534e-02 -4.793e-02
HighDenResid_Prox -1.332e-01 -7.484e-02 -6.986e-02 -9.399e-02
Wet_proximity      6.097e-01 -3.137e-01  1.236e-01  2.939e-02
Wetland            1.126e+01  3.303e+00 -1.191e+00  3.162e-02


For sharing images, one can literally just copy and paste an image into the question if its a screenshot.

Thanks Shawn. I don't seem to be able to get it to work that way either. No big deal though, as the example scores tell the story.

There are at least 7 types of scaling that can be applied to the species scores. Which did you use?

Do the landscape features sum to near 100? Wild guess but this could be related to the use of proportion data.
